# Running xampp and utserver simultaneously

Tags: xampp, utorrent

I recently installed *xampp* on my ubuntu 16.04. But it wasn't working properly. ProFTPD failure was occurring.Today I started the *utserver* and found that it wasn't working properly. I had used it previously and it used to work perfectly. I thought there might be some port error due to *xampp* and I decided to uninstall it. After uninstalling *xampp* utserver was running perfectly again. My question is: Was it because of *xampp* that I couldn't use *u torrent*.
If yes can someone suggest a way to run both applications simultaneously without errors?

Comment: Well, check the documentation of utserver (never used that myself) for what ports is uses / requires / tries to bind to. Xampp will use the ports of the packaged applications: 80, 443, 3306, (21). Certainly it might also be that you ran into a simple resource issue with the system you operate on, memory or computation power.

Comment: @arkascha , utserver uses port 80

Comment: Ok, so there you have your answer, right?